# Postman collection runner with big numbers on csv file

Tags: csv, postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm having trouble with Postman's collection runner as the csv file I import is previewed with scientific numbers. The numbers are somehow converted in the request as well...

- csv file excerpt :

```
19951195954805,19951195954805171182512001,1555,1500,2017-06-01T10:00:00+02:00,47.237605,6.022034,2017-06-04T10:00:00+02:00,FIAT,FR,BB-000-AA
```

The second value is `apaId` which is used in the request sent. Its variable name in the request body is **id_FPS**.

- Request body excerpt :

```
"apaId": {{id_FPS}},
```

- Request sent :

```
"apaId": 1.995119595480517e+25,
```

Is there a way to force Postman to use the number I put on the csv file? This number isn't random, it is meaningful with a set number of characters.

Comment: Hello, when you select your csv file in Postman runner, does the preview shows the full data or the exponential form ? I tried a similar case with a value as long as yours and, in my request body, the data is correctly displayed.